# One more step for showing the isomorphism between $\pi_1(S^1)$ and $\pi_1(\Bbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\})$

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Show that $\pi_1(S^1)$ and $\pi_1(\Bbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\})$ are isomorphic.

Let $X=\Bbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$ and $f:X\to S^1$ be the retraction
$$
f(x)=\frac{x}{|x|}. 
$$
Let $a\in S^1$. I have shown that the induced homomorphism $f_*:\pi_1(X,a)\to\pi_1(S^1,a)$ is surjective.

Here is my **question**:

Could anyone help me showing that $f_*$ is also injective?

Answer (score 1):

Let $H(t,x)=(1-t)x+tx/{\|x\|}$ defined on $R^2-0$, $H(0,x)=x$ and $H(1,x)=x/{\|x\|}$ and the restriction of $H$ to $S^1$ is the identity, thus $S^1$ is a retract of $R^2-0$ thus $S^1$ and $R^2-0$ have the same homotopy in particular $\pi_1(S^1)=\pi_1(R^2-0)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If the injective property of $f_*$ implicitly done in your answer somewhere?